# ViewBag showing &39; within text

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Within jquery I am getting the value of the value from the ViewBag.VendorName:

```
    $('#VendorName').attr('value', '@ViewBag.VendorName');
```

to a text box. The value of ViewBag.VendorName on the controller is: "Anthony's"
In the View, it shows up as: Anthony&39;s

Any idea on how I can fix this so the view can show Anthony's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Javascript-encode the string:

```
"@Html.Raw(Server.JavaScriptStringEncode(ViewBag.VendorName, false))"
```

The `Html.Raw` prevents in from being HTML-encoded, which is messing you up.

Comment: Thanks but how do  show @Html.Raw within a text box as I need it in @Html.TextBox( ..

Comment: `Html.TextBox` will do that for you.  Just call it normally.